# Crystal Report 10 with vb 6

Tags: vb6

I have Crystal report 10

I try to use the Crystal Activex Report Viewer Library 10
(CRViewer.dll) but :

-in Visual Basic 6.0 IDE i obtain the errore "error accessing the
system registry"
-using regsvr32  "C:\programmi\Business Objects\Common
\3.5\crystalreportviewers10\ActiveXControls\CRViewer.dll" i obtain
the error 0x8002801c (...problem with registry...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you don't have the correct permissions. Are you logged in as administrator on the machine?
Otherwise, you probably need to be.

If you are logged in as administrator, but it's still not working, then your registry might have non-default security settings, you can change this by using the `regedit` tool, and to find out which keys it's trying to access you can use the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), just start up that tool and set it to log registry accesses and then try to use the dll again and then see what it tried to do.